Warning caused by itemindent from enumitem
Consider the following MWE:
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}[
  label = \CheckBox{},
  itemindent = * % this line causes the warning
]
  \item
  First item
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}

\end{document}

When I compile using lualatex, I get the warning
LaTeX Warning: Reference `HyAnn@1' on page 0 undefined on input line 14.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd){/usr/local/texliv
e/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} [1] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

but when I compile the same document after removing the line itemindent = *, it compiles without any warning.
How do I fix this?

You can't fix that, I will have to correct the code in the pdfmanagement (due to the itemindent the \CheckBox is executed inside a \settowidth and the label is not created there).

@UlrikeFischer Okay; thank's for det clarification. Will this update come "soon" (where "soon" is up to you to decide)?

well actually it is not trivial. The only way I see to avoid it is to remove the specific missing label message and to issue only a generic "LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references." at the end. (BTW: You get a similar message also without \DocumentMetadata if you load zref-abspage before hyperref, so it is not a new problem.).

@UlrikeFischer I see. Thank you very much for the heads up!

after looking at it (also for the new form code in l3pdffield-testphase) I think you should avoid for now to use form fields in places with such measuring code. It will break with tagging too.
